# Adding data to an existing xml file

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I am using the follwing syntax to add data to already existing xml file in the following way:

```
XmlTextReader Reader = new XmlTextReader("ServerPaths.xml");
        DataSet dsNewList = new DataSet();
        dsNewList.ReadXml(Reader);
        Reader.Close();
        DataTable dt = dsNewList.Tables[0];
        dt.Rows.Add(txtNewServerPath.Text);
        dt.WriteXml("ServerPaths.xml",false);
```

But, i was getting error at last line as:

```
System.IO.IOException was unhandled
          Message=The process cannot access the file 'C:\Documents and Settings\590000\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\EasyDeployer\EasyDeployer\bin\Debug\ServerPaths.xml' because it is being used by another process
```

Please help in solving this error. or is there any other way to do this?

My xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ServerList>
<ServerPath>C:\\Avinash\\Dev1</ServerPath>
<ServerPath>C:\\Avinash\\Dev1</ServerPath>
</ServerList>
```

I just wanted to add new serverpath..

Comment: Maybe try Reader.Flush();

Comment: Do you have the file open while you're running this?

Comment: Reader.Flush() is not available

Comment: No..The file is closed.

Comment: Try Reader.Dispose() after you're done reading the file.

Comment: Reader.Dispose() not available..its a XMLTextReader.it has only close() method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also try adding XmlNode's to the xml document like this:

```
XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
xd.Load("ServerPaths.xml");

XmlNode rootNode = xd.DocumentElement;
XmlNode serverPathNode = xd.CreateElement("ServerPath");
serverPathNode.InnerText = txtNewServerPath.Text; // Your value

rootNode.AppendChild(serverPathNode);

xd.Save("ServerPaths.xml");
```

Comment: Do you have the XML document open somewhere else? Like an editor?

Comment: The file is in the debug folder of the applciation, is it creating any problem?

Comment: No,it is completely closed

Comment: It's somehow locked, are you using this file in any other way in your code? And maybe not closing the connection? You could also try using another file.

Comment: Got..it..Thanks. yes it was opened in other part of code..now i closed it by using Reader.close()

Comment: That exception is raised because the file is locked. You either have another handle on it i.e. you are loading that XmlDocument somewhere else in your program or have it open in visual studio (or another editor). Do you have another instance of the App running which is accessing it?